# add a div dynamically after two divs of the element

Tags: jquery

I have a text box element. I am doingvalidation for that field and need to add an error message dynamically to that field.

```
<div class="abc xyz">
    <input  class="class1" type="text" id="test1" name="test1" value="test" title="Invalid input"/>
    <div class="aux-content"><p>Aux content1</p></div>  
    <div class="aux-content"><p>Aux content2.</p></div>                     
</div>
```

JS function

```
function validate(){
    var returnVal = true;
    var input = $('#test1');
    input.next('div.error').remove();
    input.removeClass('wrong');
    input.removeClass('correct');
    if(input.val() == 0)
    {    
        input.addClass('wrong');
        var title = input.attr('title');
        input.after('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        returnVal = true;
    }
    return returnVal;
}

('#subBtn').click(function(){
var retVal = validate();
});

$('#test1').blur(validate);
```

In the validate(0 function i need to check if value is null. If so i need to display the error message below the Aux Content2 div. Currently its displaying error just after the text box. But I want after the aux content2. How can I do that?

Thank

Comment: Just put a empty div after the Aux Content2 div and use that to put the error in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i thnik this would help;

```
  if(input.val() == 0)
    {    
        input.addClass('wrong');
        var title = input.attr('title');
        var _error_ul = $('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>')
                        .insertAfter(input.nextAll(".aux-content:last"));
    }
```

Comment: Is it good way if I write like this to display error input.next().next().after('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>'); and input.next().next().next('ul.error').remove(); to remove the error?

Comment: i just edited my code (i didin't read your question well before :s

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
            if(input.val() == 0)
            {    
                input.addClass('wrong');
                var parent = input.parent();
                var error_div = parent.find('.aux-content').eq(2);
                var title = input.attr('title');
                error_div.html('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>');
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Is it good way if I write like this to display error input.next().next().after('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>'); and input.next().next().next('ul.error').remove(); to remove the error?

Comment: @user1049057 yes it is way, you should avoid this,because in case you need to make some change in html , then your javascript code also need to be change.  so instead of getting second div apply class on your div, so with class you can access error div directly no matter how many div you include or remove or change order of your div